# Overloading MySQL stored functions

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

When I try to create stored functions with the same names but different signatures:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `max`(a INT, b INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF a > b THEN RETURN a; ELSE RETURN b; END IF;
END

CREATE FUNCTION `max`(a DATE, b DATE) RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    IF a > b THEN RETURN a; ELSE RETURN b; END IF;
END
```

MySQL gives me an error:

> FUNCTION max already exists

Do I really have to give distinct names to the functions like `max_tinyint`, `max_int`, `max_date`, `max_datetime`, etc.?

Even easier would be if I could create a function that accepts arbitrary types as parameters.

Comment: The snarky answer would be that MySQL already has a MAX function....

Comment: It does finally!? Since when? (You don't mean the aggregate function, do you? That's a whole different thing.)

Comment: Well, I DID mean the aggregate function, but it does have a greatest function

Comment: @AndreKR: it always had `GREATEST()`/`LEAST()` ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

mysql doesn't support function overloading. So the only way for you is to create functions with different names

**UPD**: and, yes, mysql has [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to do what you want

Comment: OMG, I've been using MySQL for years. How could this evade my mind for so long? Thank you, thank you, thank you.